# Status bar goes black after unplugging charging cable

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistatusbar

I am having difficulties with status bar. I currently use it with `Default` setting in storyboard in my `UIViewController`.

I am testing it with real device. Before I unplug the charging cable it shows a blue status bar which is normal. But after I unplug it, it displays a black status bar. Below you can see the problem with images.

before unplugging charging cable:

[image]

after unplugging charging cable:

[image]

Comment: Storyboard view controller status bar means nothing.  You need to use [[NSApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent].

Comment: No difference. still same.

Comment: just realized the blue is because you are connected via hotspot.  anyway, in your app delegate didfinishloadingwithoptions method add `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];`

Comment: I ve done this but its not working. Still black thing happens

Comment: The blue bar is when you connect to hotspot so it's not clear what you're doing right or wrong. If you tried certain things you need to explain what you did so people know you're not stupid or they won't waste their time like me trying to help you

Comment: Your picture doesn't illustrate the fact you unplugged battery charger but that you're on hotspot and then you're not

Comment: If you have a view controller and the root view is colorless and it has a sub view clipped at the top this is what you'll have